# Prevent a closed window from being added into session?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm trying open `extension://<my extension>/popup.html` in a popup window by using [`chrome.windows.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create)

The problem I'm trying to fix is when that window is closed, it's being added into recently closed list ([`chrome.sessions.getRecentlyClosed`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sessions/#method-getRecentlyClosed))

I've tried open it in `incognito` window, but browser doesn't allow `extension://` urls there.

Is there a way prevent it from being added into sessions, or even better be able delete item from sessions?

Comment: It seems that there's only this function: [`sessions.forgetClosedWindow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sessions/forgetClosedWindow) can remove the closed window from the session, but it's not supported by Edge and Chrome. I didn't find other ways to remove from or prevent the closed window from being added into the session.

Comment: *Manifest: MV3* 
I'm stuck with the same situation. What I've decided to do was to refrain from using the defalt close button of the window when closing the Popup.. I instead updated the window state to `chrome.windows.update(windowId, {state: "minimise"}, callback)` the window and when I need the popup back I just update the window to `chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true}, callback)`. 

There seems to be no other way AFAIK in chrome.

Comment: Make sure to set the window type to `"popop"` too.